# Checkstyle and JAVA8 lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8, checkstyle

I'm preparing large migration to JAVA8. Part of it is configuring checkstyle to properly work with JAVA8 constructions. I try to keep checkstyle synchronized with a default autoformatting tool in IntelliJ. Unfortunately it doesn't accept automatic IntelliJ indentation of lambda expressions.

checkstyle.xml

```
<module name="Indentation">
     <property name="caseIndent" value="0"/>
</module>
```

Code:

```
public class Java8CheckstyleTest {
    public void java8Elements(String ala) {
        Collections.sort(names, (String a, String b) -> {
            return b.compareTo(a); // <<<25 line
        }); // <<<26 line
    }
}
```

Checkstyle report:

> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:25: 'block' child have incorrect indentation
>   level 12, expected level should be 16.
>
> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:26: 'block rcurly' have incorrect indentation
>   level 16, expected level should be 12.

If I break "})" with a new line and autoformat:

```
public class Java8CheckstyleTest {
    public void java8Elements(String ala) {
        Collections.sort(names, (String a, String b) -> {
                    return b.compareTo(a); // <<<25 line
                } // <<<26 line
        ); 
    }
}
```

i get:

> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:25: 'block' child have incorrect indentation
>   level 20, expected level should be 16.
>
> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:26:'block rcurly' have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 12.

How should I configure checkstyle not to break old code and to accept these autoformatting schemes?

EDIT: I updated checkstyle to 6.11.1 and as I see problem is nearly solved. First code is accepted right now. Second produces report:

> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:32: error: 'block' child have incorrect
>   indentation level 20, expected level should be one of the following:
>   12, 16.
>
> Java8CheckstyleTest.java:33: error: 'block rcurly' have incorrect
>   indentation level 16, expected level should be one of the following:
>   8, 12.

I assume that it's probably a thing that have to be fixed in the next IntelliJ version. I will close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
      <version>6.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

to the maven checkstyle plugin configuration solved a problem. Details in main thread.